# Smarty 3: how can I output a variable and not have html entities converted?

Tags: smarty

In a specific template, I'd like to be able to output a variable, and not have the quotes, such as ' turned into html entity codes (&#039;)

How can I do that without affecting how the rest of the system is working?

I've tried:

{$var|escape:'html'}

{$var|escape:'htmlall'}

{$var|unescape}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make a variable exempt from default modifiers, add the 'nofilter' attribute to the output tag such as `{$var nofilter}`

Comment: THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU! So much headache and time lost...